# SQL How to group different values in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query to group all by country some data; the query is the following

```
select
    sum(uwm.amount) as amountInbound,
    au.country as country
from user_wallet_movement uwm
LEFT JOIN user_wallet uw on uwm.wallet_id = uw.id
JOIN app_user au on uw.user_id = au.id
where status = "execute" and direction = "inbound" and mov_date > "2020-07-01"
GROUP BY au.country
;
```

This query works quite well but the data in the database are dirty so sometimes I get, for example, Italy which can be written like IT or ITA or Italy.
So, what I want is the same query but when the data is ITA or Italy to be grouped under IT

I changed my query like this

```
select
    sum(uwm.amount) as amountInbound,
    IF(au.country = "ITA", "IT", IF(au.country = "Italia", "IT", au.country)) as country
from user_wallet_movement uwm
LEFT JOIN user_wallet uw on uwm.wallet_id = uw.id
JOIN app_user au on uw.user_id = au.id
where status = "execute" and direction = "inbound" and mov_date > "2020-07-01"
GROUP BY country
;
```

but in this way I don't get a group, but just three times appearing IT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend `case` for this purpose.  Second, give the column a different name in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN au.country IN ('ITA', 'ITALIA') THEN 'IT'
             ELSE au.country
        END) as country_code
       SUM(uwm.amount) as amountInbound
FROM user_wallet_movement uwm LEFT JOIN
     user_wallet uw 
     ON uwm.wallet_id = uw.id JOIN
     app_user au
     ON uw.user_id = au.id
WHERE status = 'execute' and direction = 'inbound' and mov_date > '2020-07-01'
GROUP BY country_code;
```

Note that the `LEFT JOIN` is useless because the second `JOIN` turns it into an `INNER JOIN`.  You should also qualify the columns in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
select
    sum(uwm.amount) as amountInbound,
    country2 as country
from (
    select
        *,
        IF(au.country = "ITA", "IT", IF(au.country = "Italia", "IT", au.country)) as country2
    from user_wallet_movement
) uwm
LEFT JOIN user_wallet uw on uwm.wallet_id = uw.id
JOIN app_user au on uw.user_id = au.id
where status = "execute" and direction = "inbound" and mov_date > "2020-07-01"
GROUP BY country2
;
```